# My loop makes a click noise each time it starts

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

**The loop plays smoothly in audacity but when I run it in the device or simulator it clicks each loop at different intensities.**

Im using .flac format because it's the only one not adding a little silence at the start/end of each file like mp3 or m4a and is not heavy like wav.

I config the session at App level:

```
//Audio
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers])
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("Setting category session for AVAudioSession Failed")
        }
```

And then I made my method on my class:

```
    //PlaySound
func playSound(soundId: Int) {
    let sound = ModelData.shared.sounds[soundId]
    
    if let bundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound.filename, ofType: "flac") {
               let backgroundMusic = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bundle)
               do {
                   audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:backgroundMusic as URL)
                   audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
                   audioPlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1 // for infinite times
                   audioPlayer?.play()
                   isPlayingSounds = true
               } catch {
                   print(error)
               }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any clue?

EDIT: If I use AVQueuePlayer and repeat the item the click noise disappear (but its no use, because I would need to repeat it indefinitely  without wasting memory), if I use AVLooper I get a silence between loops. All with the same sound. Idk :/